# How to return the error description in a invalid JSON request body to the client in Rust?

Tags: rust, actix-web

In Python, I can use [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [Pydantic](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic) to validate user input just by defining a schema (much like a Rust struct). Then using that schema, Marshmallow loads the user input and returns the error it finds. Such as:

[image]

[image]

I can have custom error handle in actix-web by implementing `ResponseError`.

**But, how can I return the description (position/field of invalid value) in a bad request body to the client?**

[image]

Comment: I apologize for misleading you: my earlier comment said "don't post code as text" but I actually meant "post code as text, not *images*". (It was still early in the morning here, if that's an excuse...) Text is good.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am always looking for answers.

Unfortunately, some web frameworks including actix handle JSON error before we can do any validation. I keep searching for using various keywords. One of them is "actix-web validate JSON" which leads me to many validator crates. But I get insight from this [blog](https://blog.sentry.io/2018/12/04/safe-web-services-actix-sentry) saying that:

> Extractors are helpers that implement the FromRequest trait. In other words, they construct any object from a request and perform validation along the way. A handful of useful extractors are shipped with Actix web, such as JSON which uses serde_json to deserialize a JSON request body

So, I search for "actix Extractor" and bring me [Extractor Doc](https://actix.rs/docs/extractors/) and [custom handling of extractor errors](https://github.com/actix/actix-web/issues/181)

So this snippet is taken from [this boilerplate](https://github.com/zupzup/rust-web-example/blob/ae230ce2e77dc0306fea5a342f75aaa856ebb191/src/handlers/mod.rs#L34) solves my current problem.

```
   App::new()
       .configure(health::init)
       .configure(students::init)
+      .app_data(web::JsonConfig::default().error_handler(|err, _req| {
+          error::InternalError::from_response(
+              "",
+              HttpResponse::BadRequest()
+                  .content_type("application/json")
+                  .body(format!(r#"{{"error":"{}"}}"#, err)),
+          )
+          .into()
+      }))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: "format!(r#"{{"error":"{}"}}"#, err)" this does not escape the string. if err contains " or other "magic" json characters it will create an invalid json document

Comment: I just realized the same as QueryConfig for query params. Thx.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @azzamsa. Is it possible to give details about the field where the type mismatch occured ? expected a string at line .... is not a great convenience for client consuming the api. I'd love to find a way to return for example "expected a string for firstname but got integer"

Comment: Did you find a solution @shellking4 ? I'm also looking for the same customization